# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert. Uniswap Error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, blockchain, uniswap

I have implemented the Uniswap v2 router function called

```
function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

I implemented it like this...

```
function swapTokensForExactEthTest(
        uint256 _amountOut,
        address _tokenIn,
        uint256 _amountInMax,
        address _to
    ) external {
        IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountInMax);
        IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, _amountInMax);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = WETH;

        IUniswapV2Router01(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS).swapTokensForExactETH(
            _amountOut,
            _amountInMax,
            path,
            _to,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

and testing it like this...

```
//WBTC_WHALE=0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC
const WHALE = process.env.WBTC_WHALE;
const AMOUNT_OUT_MIN = 1;
const TOKEN_IN = WBTC; //0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599
const AMOUNT_IN = 100000000;


it('should swap tokens for exact eth', async()=>{

        tokenIn = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_IN);
        testUniswap = await TestUniswap.new();

        await testUniswap.swapTokensForExactEthTest(

            AMOUNT_OUT_MIN,
            tokenIn.address,
            AMOUNT_IN,
            accounts[0],

            {
                from: WHALE
            }

        );

        console.log(`sent ${balanceOf(accounts[0])}`);

    });
```

My problem is when I'm testing it like the testing code above, I'm getting...

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

and when I'm commenting out the line `console.log(`sent ${balanceOf(accounts[0])}`);` then I'm again getting the same balance.

Anyone please help.

Comment: I found the error from remix. 

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

Gas estimation: 0x2dc6c0
Gas limit: 0x2dc6c0

but how can I solve this...

Comment: I added but the compiler shows...

Cannot set option "value" on a non-payable function type.

for swapTokensForExactETH function

Comment: Sorry, my bad I read it wrong, you should **not** use value in this case. The only thing missing is WHALE have to approve testUniswap's address.