# swapTokensForExactETH, execution reverted: null

Tags: web3js, nodejs, bsc, pancakeswap

I m trying to estimate gas for a `swapTokensForExactETH` transaction with pancakeswap contract (similar to uniswap one)

When i do, i get the following error: `Error: Returned error: execution reverted null`

After some [research](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120324/error-returned-error-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-revert-uniswa#comment143259_120324) it appears i shouldn't give the `value` field when building the transaction with this contract method. But when i don't provide this field, i get the following error: `Error: Returned error: execution reverted: PancakeRouter: EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT`, same goes if i put 0 in `value`

For reference:

- Using Binance Smart Chain
- 0.00024 BNB = 1 Token.
- I have 10 tokens in my wallet + 1 BNB.
- I have approved the token on Pancakeswap
- I did manage to use `swapExactETHForTokens` successfully already, but not `swapTokensForExactETH` yet

```js
// For your information:
// `CNF.wallet` = My wallet address
// `config.token.contract`= `0x00e1656e45f18ec6747f5a8496fd39b50b38396d` (BCOIN)
// `config.crypto.bnb.contract` = `0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c`
// `config.crypto.pancake.router.contract` = `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` 



var amountToGet = 0.00024; //exact amount of BNB that i want (equal to 1 token)
var amountOutMax = 5; //max amount of tokens i m willing to use to get above BNB amount

var data = contract.methods.swapTokensForExactETH(
    web3_bsc.utils.toHex(amountToGet), 
    web3_bsc.utils.toHex(amountOutMax),
    [config.token.contract, config.crypto.bnb.contract],
    CNF.wallet,
    web3_bsc.utils.toHex(Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20), //deadline
);

var count = await web3_bsc.eth.getTransactionCount(CNF.wallet);
var rawTransaction = {
    "from": CNF.wallet,
    "gasLimit": web3_bsc.utils.toHex(CNF.gasmax),
    "to": config.crypto.pancake.router.contract,
    // "value":web3_bsc.utils.toHex(amountToGet),
    // "value": 0,
    "data": data.encodeABI(),
    "nonce": web3_bsc.utils.toHex(count)
};


web3_bsc.eth.estimateGas(rawTransaction, (error, gasEstimate) => {

   if (!error && gasEstimate) {
   
        //continue...
   }
   else {
   
        //error
   }
   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to convert the amounts from ether to wei.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#towei

Amounts sent in ethereum contracts are `uint256`, you must convert your floating point `ether` value to `wei` unit, which is done by multiplying by the number of decimal points a token has.

`WBNB` and your token are using 18 decimals, so call

```
web3_bsc.utils.toHex(web3_bsc.utils.toWei(amountToGet)),
web3_bsc.utils.toHex(web3_bsc.utils.toWei(amountOutMax)),
```

Your `amountInMax` is "5", this means 0.00000000000000005 BCOIN, hence `EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT` is thrown.

---

`swapTokensForExactETH` swaps an unknown amount of Token into exact ETH.

You shouldn't specify `value` since you're receiving ETH (BNB in this case) and `value` sends ETH along to the contract.

According to [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swaptokensforexacteth) -

```
function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
  external
  returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

- `amountOut` is the amount of ETH to receive.
- `amountInMax` is the maximum amount of input tokens that can be required before the transaction reverts.

The `EXCESSIVE_INPUT_AMOUNT` error means that to match your requested `amountOut` (exact ETH), you must pay too much of Token, more than allowed in `amountInMax`. This means you're not calculating enough slippage in `amountInMax` to sustain normal price fluctuations.

If you want this to work in real time, you should use UniswapSDK to calculate `inputAmount` using the [Trade](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/2.0.0/reference/trade) object, then add 0.1% for slippage and use that for `maxInputAmount`.

Make sure you have enough of Token in your wallet to cover this.

Comment: when i put 0.00024 BNB on [pancakeswap BCOIN token swap page](https://pancakeswap.finance/swap?outputCurrency=0x00e1656e45f18ec6747f5a8496fd39b50b38396d) for `swapTokensForExactETH` it request around 0.99 tokens. I have 10 tokens on my wallet and 1 BNB. I don't understand why i still get the error on my script (i allow 6 tokens in `amountInMax` which is already 6 times more than what is estimated on pancakeswap. I ve also tried with 0.0000024 which is much lower but same error

Comment: added the solution

Comment: That was it.. i was already doing it but during my debug i tried without it for `amountInMax` and forgot to put it back... thanks a lot for your help